# Send multiple qsub jobs with different runtime parameters

Tags: bash, cluster-computing, qsub

Last night, I sent a large number of jobs with `qsub` of the same executable but with different input parameters. Most of the jobs were in queue, waiting for the others to finish. This morning, I realized that all the jobs that were in queue used the last instance of my input file.

What is the standard way of working around this issue? Should I have one input file per job and compile my code so it reads the correct one? Or is there a better/more robust solution?

Comment: did you modify a `pbs` script between each `qsub`?

Comment: @gauteh no I did not. My (silly) mistake is that I assumed the input file would be read when I send the job, which does not make sense. However, I find that having N different input files for the N simulations, requiring N recompilation to be very ineffective. So I'm thinking there must be a better way of doing things

Comment: If you modify the executable to take input arguments on the command line rather than being defined at compile time, then you can use an approach as described below. You could also wrap your executable in a script which gives more complicated input parameters than simple numbers which are easier to deal with in the PBS script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a master PBS script which loops over the different input paramters, executes them either in parallel or sequentially:

this simply gives `executable` a different input number for each job (`IN`), you should change this to loop over one or more of your input parameters as needed.

```
# PBS -l mppwidth=2048

NIN=10 # number of input parameters

for IN in `seq -w 1 $NIN`; do
   cd "sub_job_${IN}"
   executable $IN # runs jobs sequentially (you might have to prefix this with aprun)
done
```

or in parallel:

```
# PBS -l mppwidth=2048
# ^^ these should now be shared among the jobs.

NIN=10 # number of input parameters

for IN in `seq -w 1 $NIN`; do
   cd "sub_job_${IN}"
   executable $IN & # runs the job in the background, you might 
                    # have to prefix this with `aprun -n .. -N ..` or something
                    # so that each job only uses a portion of the total
                    # requested CPUs.
done
wait # wait for all jobs to finish
```

Comment: TBH, I had already thought of something like this but I thought there had to be a better/cleaner way. Thank you for the solution though! The best solution could just be to have a python script edit my input files and launch the simulations one after the other...

Comment: Yes, I frequently use python as a master script myself launching each job as a thread using the ThreadPoolExecutor (with a aprun launch in each process). In this way you can leverage the simple python interface to keep track of your jobs.